# Conditional independence in EM algorithm

Tags: expectation-maximization, graphical-model

Let $X$, $\theta$ and $Z$ denote observed, parameter and latent nodes in a graphical model. The EM algorithm attempts to find a local maximum likelihood estimate $\theta^\ast$ for the likelihood of observing the data $X$ under the parameter $\theta$.

In the E-step, a certain quantity is integrated against the conditional distribution of $Z$ given the current estimate of the parameter $\theta^{(t)}$ and the data $X$.

What happens if the latent variable is conditionally independent of the parameter given the data, i.e. $p(Z \mid \theta^{(t)}, X) = p(Z \mid X)$? The quantity in the E-step no longer depends on the current estimate of the parameter, and the algorithm would terminate in one step. Is it still valid to apply the EM-algorithm to obtain a local maximum? Does the EM-algorithm reduce to a simpler principle?

Answer (score 0):

The reason we use EM algorithm is that we have an intractable posterior. But if your latent observation is not dependent on the parameters, there seems to be no reason to apply EM algorithm. You can use gradient ascent for convergence.

Comment: But just because the latent is not dependent on the parameters, does not mean that the integral is tractable. In contrast, the integral against the logarithm of the complete likelihood may be tractable.

Comment: I did not completely understand your comment. I wanted to say was that if I do have a conditional dependence of latent variable on parameters, I would go for a simpler convergence approach rather than using EM algorithm.